# How to get the Minimum/Maximum value from the Range attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

The View I have added looks as below and I have used the Range Attribute for Model.

```
@Model System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RangeAttribute
@{Layout = null;}

@Html.Hidden("IncludedValidators", "RangeAttribute")


<div class="page-header">
    <h4>
        MinMaxRangeValidator
    </h4>
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:RemoveValidation(MinMaxRangeValidator);"><span class="icon-remove pull-right"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Minimum, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Minimum, new { @class = "input-medium" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Maximum, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Maximum, new { @class = "input-medium" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.ErrorMessage, new { @class = "control-label" })
    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.ErrorMessage, new { @class = "input-medium" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And My controller Looks like:

```
public ActionResult AddValidator(string validatorType)
{
    ValidationAttribute validator = null;

    switch (validatorType)
    {
        case "RequiredAttribute":
            validator = new RequiredAttribute();
            break;
        case "RangeAttribute":
            validator = new RangeAttribute(minimum,maximum);
            break;
    }
}
```

How do I get the minimum and maximum values here?  I have not created a separate method under the controller for each type of validation.

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs need to be wrapped in a form like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
}
```

and your controller action should be receiving the View Model as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult AddValidator(RangeAttribute rangeAttribute)
{
    rangeAttribute.Maximum;
    rangeAttribute.Minimum;
}
```

Comment: But have a look at the controller i am using a switch case for it . should i create a separate controller method for each item then .

Comment: @JitheshChandra Well that is a different question and one that is more so a matter of opinion.  Using model binding in the way I suggested would require different actions because they require different parameters.